# How to receive an image from the server to the app

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, image, cocoa

I know how to send an image from my app to server. (PHP) Now I would like to know how to send an image to my app from the server.

I know I could made available a URL an upload the image from an URL, but is it possible to send it to the app without providing an image URL as a form of variable or something like that (and not base64 given the 33% size increase)? If it is possible could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use JSON reply with the image URL from the server. Only you received the image URL you can store the image to your app. I am a PHP developer once I work for a Android and IPhone project, I given then image URL to the App team and they followed the above method and they got success. hope this might give you some more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive a string from server which should contain image in the form of data then after receiving you can make an image from it by using [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it yourself using NSURLConnection you can make an uiimage from an NSData. Or your can use the [SDwebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) libraray which is probably the most simplest way to implement this.